# Open a website URL without Prefixing "http://"

Tags: android

1. I want my browser(I created in android) to open a URL just like this "www.google.com" but it won't. If I mention http:// with it then it does.
2. Similarly when I go to "google.com" and when I click in the edit field of the Google it doesn't bring up the keyboard.

Appreciating help.
Thanks

Comment: How should we help without knowing any details?

Comment: create a edit text  and a button in activity and in button click event get edit text value string and hit action perform at click event on button

Comment: please add sum other details to identify your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code snippet.

```
 String url = textView.getText().toString();
    if(!url.startsWith("www.")&& !url.startsWith("http://")){
      url = "www."+url;
    }
    if(!url.startsWith("http://")){
      url = "http://"+url;
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't 'startsWith' be a better choice here ?

Comment: ya, u can use startsWith.

Comment: It would avoid the whole substring code here, make it look more simplified!

Comment: String website = "http://" +url.getText().toString();
   browser.loadUrl(website); << is this an option?

Comment: My question has a second part too, any approach to that guys?

Comment: i have done webview app and in that keyboard appears and handled by webview itself. I think it's device issue try another device.

Comment: I am sorry but would you like to tell me about how to make the WebView zoomed out. I mean I don't want to see part of the page and then scroll down to see the remaining part instead I want to see the page completely like a little zoomed out or something but complete, not in parts. I used "browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);" but doesn't work for me.

Comment: try mWebView.setInitialScale(zoomLevelYouWant);